# "Determining location of DBIO file fragments."

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage, bigdata, azure-databricks, parquet

In Azure Databricks when loading data into a parquet file, the execution gets stuck at "Determining location of DBIO file fragments. This operation can take some time." without any progress at all. How can I proceed to fix it? the size of data isn't greater than few MBs

Answer (score 0):

Azure Databricks caches files from storage on the cluster virtual machines for faster access. This is called disk cache, but its former name is DBIO cache or delta cache. The cache can be an issue if you are using auto scaling, because on each scale the cache has to be written to the new VMs.
What you can try:

1. check that you are using a cluster with current datarbricks version
2. Try to run the optimize command:

   %sql

   optimize table_name

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chen, I had tried optimizing all tables, yet the same issue continues. The amount of data is not too much but if I try with lesser data this issue doesn't come up. Is there a way to validate and troubleshoot it further?

Comment: @HarshPriyadarshi ,  Try to play with the disk cache settings (increase\decrease), see the command here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/optimizations/disk-cache#--configure-the-disk-cache
If that doesn't help try using a different cluster, perhaps with more disk storage or SSD disks.

Comment: I will try to do the steps shared, will update with exact cause and solution that fixed it. Thanks a lot Chen.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the io.cache.enabled configuration will resolve the issue.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled", "false")
```